# Which model file in magento , fetch data from catalog_product_entity_text?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

How to fetch data from table `catalog_product_entity_text`?

This table contains the description of product according to store view (english, french, german).
**I want to know that which core file fetch data from this table**

Comment: To whom may concern, follow this link to understand Magento database structure: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/

Answer (score 1):

your question is somehow unclear, but I can give it a try.
Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can do this.

If you want all the data for a product, you can do this:

```
$storeId = 1; //replace with the store id you need
$productId = 15; //replace with your product id
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
```

Then you can retrieve the description like this:

```
$product->getDescription();
```

or the name

```
$product->getName();
```

if you need a certain attribute value (let's say description) for more products you can do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSort('description')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>array(1,2,3))); //filter for products with ids 1 2 and 3.
```

then you can retrieve the descriptions like this:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $description = $product->getDescription();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the description according to store view then try to set Store as below while loading specific product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
```

where `$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();` and if you want to get storeId of specific store code you can get it through `$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore('store_code')->getId();`